# How to type in one line an javascript object in Typescript, were a root property has a variable name

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, dynamic-typing

I have the following javascript object:

```
var termsAndConditions = {
    pt: ["url1", "url2"],
    en: ["url3", "url4"]
}
```

And I want to type it in Typescript in just one line. Something like this:

```
const termsAndConditions: {[countryKey: Array<string>]} = {
    pt: ["url1", "url2"],
    en: ["url3", "url4"]
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const ptUrls: Array<string> = termsAndConditions.pt;
const enUrls: Array<string> = termsAndConditions.en;
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: From the code, I can't see why you want to do that, everything can be inferred. Can you elaborate a bit more on this? You could also use something like `type T1 = typeof termsAndConditions["en"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const termsAndConditions: { [countryKey: string]: string[] } = {
    pt: ["url1", "url2"],
    en: ["url3", "url4"]
}
```

Later you do not need to add the extra typing, as it is already specified

Eg.

```
const ptUrls = termsAndCondition.pt
```

Comment: or use `Array<string>` in stead of `string[]` if you prefer

Answer (score 1):

```js
type TermAndConditions = Record<'en' | 'pt', string[]>
```

if the types are of the same value shape, you may use [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt), using union type as key for the Record will suit your situation

Comment: @arun-vinoth thx, I have added some reference links and explanation